# How Iterator-to-Iterator transformation in Spark allows spilling of Data to disk in Spark.?

Tags: apache-spark

If Iterator-to-Iterator transformation is used in MapPartiton then how will it allow spilling of data to disk. As i understand MapPartition needs whole partition in memory to process, but if i use Iterator-to-Iterator then how data can be spilled to disk (despite of fact that MapPartiton needs whole partition in memmory).

Answer (score 1):

This is a wrong notion that MapPartition needs complete data in memory.

MapPartition is just like Map with a difference it acts on a partition at a time.

1. It will read one record after another sequentially.
2. It will return once it has processes all the records.

http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/spark-map-vs-mappartitions/

Comment: i didn't say that MapPartition needs entire data in memory but it needs entire partition to fit in memory( the partition on which its working upon). Please refer link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-983.

Comment: If the partition is big and doesn't fits into the memory than how this issue is handled. As I read in High Performance Spark that Iterator-to-Iterator transformation can help in spilling data to disk. My question is how is it possible for Iterator-to-Iterator transformation (when declared inside MapPartition) to spill on disk while MapPartition need entire partition in memmory.

Answer (score 1):

> Conceptually, an iterator-to-iterator transformation means defining a
> process for evaluating elements one at a time. Thus, Spark can apply
> that procedure to batches of records rather than reading an entire
> partition into memory or creating a collection with all of the output
> records in-memory and then returning it. Consequently,
> iterator-to-iterator transformations allow Spark to manipulate
> partitions that are too large to fit in memory on a single executor
> without out memory errors.
>
> Furthermore, keeping the partition as an iterator allows Spark to use disk space more selectively. Rather than spilling an entire partition when it doesn’t fit in memory, the iterator-to-iterator transformation allows Spark to spill only those records that do not fit in memory, thereby saving disk I/O and the cost of recomputation.

Excerpts from "High Performance Spark"